# Re-trigger past instances of DAG with upstream_failed status

Tags: airflow

**Situation**: A DAG with `depends_on_past=True` is configured to run daily. Now, if for some reason DAG of previous day fails, current day's DAG task would be marked with status 'None' and wouldn't be triggered.

**Requirement**: Here we need to instead re-trigger the past day's failed tasks, followed by running the current day's DAG.

Any ideas of how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

When specifying the default_args you have the ability to state how many retries you want.

For example:

```
default_args = {
'owner': 'ANDY',
'depends_on_past': True,
'start_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
'email': ['ANDY@email.com'],
'email_on_failure': True,
'email_on_retry': False,
'retries': 3,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)}
```

The subsequent tasks will run after it finally completes as long as you set the proper upstream/downstream dependencies. I hope this helps.

Comment: Move 1 step ahead of your solution. Even after the retries, if that task fails, then on next schedule, the tasks in DAG would be in waiting state, waiting for its upstream (i.e. past day's DAG) to complete. So till the time someone does not manually re-trigger the past day's failed tasks, the schedule can never resume. We would like to remove this manual intervention.